# Как правильно отдать 404 ошибку yii2

Tags: php, yii2, http-status-code-404

Через сервис проверяю ссылку на ресурс и показывает что ошибка 302, хотя во вьюхе говорит что ошибка 404. Как сделать так что бы он реально отдавал 404 ошибку? Или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: проще всего в htaccess это делать

Comment: Что-то есть сомнения, что сервис просто ловит первый ответ, который действительно 302, но после того как отрабатавыет то, что найдено, оно возвращает 404, которую сервис и не ловит ...

Answer (score 2):

Можно выкинуть исключение

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете перехватить исключение `InvalidRouteException` в `Module::runAction()`, чтобы удостовериться, что ошибка действительно в доступе к несуществующему ресурсу. Чтобы принудительно установить код ответа в 404, Вы можете использовать метод: `Yii::$app->response->setStatusCode(404);`.

Подробнее про установку кода ответа тут: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#setStatusCode%28%29-detail